# Save a big array of numbers in a cookie

Tags: cookies

I have to save 400 numbers in a cookie on the client's side. Every numbers is from **1 to 10**. Any suggestions how to organize the data in the cookie to make it compact? (I'm going to work with the cookies using *Python* at the server side, and *JavaScript* at the client's side.)

Comment: can you give any more information about the numbers being stored?

Comment: What server side language you are using ? if php take a look : http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php for html5 you can also use localstorage

Comment: Yes, order matters very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use `localStorage':

```
for(i=0; i <400; i++){
     localStorage[i] = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
}

console.log(localStorage);
alert(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2uUn/

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you want to do this entirely on the client side, then let's try another approach.  For every three integers (from 1 to 10) that you want to store, there would be 1000 combinations (10*10*10=1000).  12 bits give you 1024 combinations (2^12=1024).  So, you can store 3 integers (each 1-10) using 12 bits.  So, 400 integers (each 1-10) could be stored using 1600 bits (400 / 3 * 12).  The logic for storing the integers bitwise this way can be implemented easily on the client side using javascript.  1600 bits = 200 bytes (1 byte = 8 bits), so you can store 400 integers (each 1-10) using 200 bytes.  This is binary data, so to store this info in a cookie, it would have to be converted to ascii text.  base64 encoding is one way to do that, and this can be done client side using the functions at [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript).  base64 encoding produces 4 characters for every 3 bytes encoded, so the resulting string that would be stored in the cookie would be 267 characters in length (20 * 4 / 3).  The whole thing can be done this way on the client-side in javascript, and 400 integers (each 1-10) could be stored in a cookie 267 characters in length.

Comment: Can anything convert the string to Unicode? This situation will mess everything.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing the list of integers to a comma-separated list, then compressing the list using gzip (which will produce binary output), then piping the binary output from gzip through a base-64 encoder, which will produce text that can be stored as a cookie.  I would guess that the result would end up being only about 100 bytes in size, which can easily be stored in a cookie.

Comment: I will have to spend server time for compressing/uncompressing for every query.